# Get Date Picked Into User Form Text Box

Tags: vba, excel, calendar, excel-2013

I have two user forms, one is a calendar that I used this guide on how to create https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class and one is where a begindate and enddate will be selected.  I am attempting to get the date selected from frmCal into a textbox on userform1.  This is how I am calling from userform1

```
Private Sub txtBegin_Enter()
  controlwithfocus = ActiveControl.Name
  frmCalendar.Show    
  UserForm1.txtBegin.Value = Calendar1.Value
End Sub
```

Which does not work, it throws an error of

> object required

Now this syntax is in the calendar code behind and is able to write to a cell problem free.  My issue is I do not want to write to a cell, I want to write to either txtBegin, or txtEnd depending on which text box "called" the form calendar to open.

```
Private Sub Calendar1_DblClick()
  ActiveCell.Value = Calendar1.Value
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

How can I modify this in order to have `Calendar1.Value` write to the "calling" text-box and not a cell on the worksheet?

**EDIT** 
And I am using Excel 2013 64 Bit edition

Comment: what line is the error thrown at?

Comment: you might need to declare the date variable that is being transferred as public. Its hard to say though without seeing too much more

Comment: Could it be that you need to reference the form the calendar control is on?  ie frmCalendar.Calendar1.Value

Answer (score 1):

You're unloading `frmCalendar` and then trying to read a value from it.  You need to create a non-default instance of the calendar form (using `New`).  Then instead of calling `Unload Me` in `Calendar1_DblClick`, use `Me.Hide` to return execution to the calling code:

In `frmCalendar`:

```
Private Sub Calendar1_DblClick()
    ActiveCell.Value = Calendar1.Value
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

In `UserForm1`:

```
Private Sub txtBegin_Enter()
    controlwithfocus = ActiveControl.Name
    With New frmCalendar                      'Create a new form instance
        .Show
        txtBegin.Value = .Calendar1.Value     'Form is hidden, but not unloaded.
    End With                                  'Form unloads here.
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error of Method or data member not found on .Calendar1  If I remove the "." I get a debug error of 'Object Required'

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - Make `Calendar1` public instead of private.

Comment: Calendar1 = New cCalendar (syntax from the link I posted that I followed to set-up this)

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - Just followed the link.  You need to change `Private WithEvents Calendar1 As cCalendar` to `Public WithEvents Calendar1 As cCalendar`

Comment: That removes the compile error, and if I hover over .Calendar1.Value it shows the value, but I still get a debug error of object required.

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - Remove the line `Set Calendar1 = Nothing` from the `QueryClose` event.

Comment: Same issue - debug error of object required.  It will write to a cell problem free, but not back to the text box on the "caller" form

Comment: Do you have a textbox named `txtBegin`?

Comment: Yes - textbox is named txtBegin

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - I can't replicate that behavior at all. Does `txtBegin.Value = "foo"` work on that line instead?